# How to temporary redirect given pages in codeigniter using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I would redirect with htaccess all codeigniter pages with following url to a coming soon page

*.domain.ext/customer/any_page

to /customer/comingsoon

any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the routing facility in CodeIgniter?

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'customer/comingsoon';
```

or

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'customer/comingsoon';
```

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)
RewriteRule /(.*) http://domain.ext/customer/coomingsoon
```

Comment: I need the simplest and easy way to change it without access to codeigniter code.

Comment: Furthemore, CI user guide says:
Route rules are not filters! Setting a rule of e.g. ‘foo/bar/(:num)’ will not prevent controller Foo and method bar to be called with a non-numeric value if that is a valid route.